# jquery getjson success function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

So first, I'm using wampserver as my local web server, my website link from my local environment is `http:\\localhost\dev\mywebsite` and I have a local `JSON` file (`country.json`) in the website root directory (`http:\\localhost\dev\mywebsite\country.json`) and then I tried to load that and tried to render the data from that json file using

```
$.getJSON('http:\\localhost\dev\mywebsite\country.json',function(e){

    console.log(e);

});
```

but not working like, I can see on my network tab from the developer console (chrome) that the json file was there but this

> console.log(e);

were not triggered. Any ideas, help please? no errors on the console tho'

Comment: Is the file accesible via URL? I mean, writing the URL `ttp:\\localhost\dev\mywebsite\country.json` directly in the browser

Comment: The path is incorrect, `\ ` in JS is an escape character, use `/` instead. You're actually trying to read the JSON from "http:\localhostdevmywebsitecountry.json".

Comment: @MrMins yes, browsing the json file directly on the browser with http://localhost/dev/mywebsite/country.json is working

Comment: @Teemu then why i see it from the network tab of developers console (chrome) that it was loaded if you say the path is incorrect?

Comment: I've no clue, maybe the path is wrong in the post only?

Comment: @teemu its not a post request, its a get request.

Comment: @JuliverGalleto Is the problem with all the browser or only with Chrome???

Comment: In this post, in the question ... Are you sure you're looking at the correct console? If the path includes backslashes like in the question, it really is not possible to load the file.

Comment: @JuliverGalleto One more scenario is possible, that the response whatever you are getting is not a valid JSON. Try to validate the JSON response using some JSON validator.

Comment: @Shiladitya its valid, im sure of it, the problem is even putting alert event inside function(e){ }, event is not triggered

Comment: @JuliverGalleto Try this `$.getJSON("http:\\localhost\dev\mywebsite\country.json", function() {
  alert("success");
})
.success(function() { alert("second success"); })
.error(function() { alert("error"); })` and let me know what you are receiving

Answer (score 0):

Your path is incorrect because `\` is an escape character in JS strings.

```
'http:\\localhost\dev\mywebsite\country.json'
/* ends up looking like this `http:\localhostdevmywebsitecountry.json`*/
/* should be: */
'http://localhost/dev/mywebsite/country.json'
```

Answer (score 0):

Should use slash not backslash

```
$.getJSON('http://localhost/dev/mywebsite/country.json',function(e){

    console.log(e);// Works OK

});
```

Or you can use fetch(with Promise like)

```
fetch('http://localhost/dev/mywebsite/country.json')
   .then(e => e.json())
   .then(e => console.log(e));
```

Or you can use fetch(with async/await)

```
 (async ()=> {
     const res = await fetch('http://localhost/dev/mywebsite/country.json')
     const json = res.json();
     console.log('json', json)
 })();
```